# Convert existing generics to diamond syntax

Tags: java, generics, java-7

I rather like the diamond syntax for generics that Java 7 introduces - not so much from a time saving perspective (after all most IDEs fill that bit in for you anyway) but just because it makes the code look a bit cleaner. Because of this and other reasons (mainly the fact I'm developing a new piece of software and some of the new APIs in Java 7 will be useful) I'm most likely going to switch the existing codebase to use / require Java 7.

However there's a fair chunk already written pre-diamond syntax, and I'd like to consistently use the diamond syntax throughout. Is there an IDE shortcut (I'm using Netbeans but obviously can open the project in any free IDE to do the task) or something else that can automatically switch the existing generic code to use diamond syntax?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of this for eclipse. But this should be doable quite easily with a 30line python script.

Comment: Well, not optimal but .. Find and Replace?

Comment: That will hardly work. You need a bit more logic for that to work correctly, but certainly doable with a few Regex and a python script

Comment: Some links for folks who are unfamiliar with diamond syntax: [Type Inference for Generic Instance Creation](http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html) and [Dustin's Blog: JDK 7: The Diamond Operator](http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/7567)

Comment: @Voo I've no problem doing it with a custom script if it comes down to that - I just wondered if there was anything out there already to save me reinventing the wheel. IntelliJ often has features like this tucked away for instance; I thought it possible that someone else had encountered or thought of this situation already and provided such a tool built in.

Comment: You could use annotation processing.

Comment: @berry120 I assumed that and sure you can save some time (and especially get it done 100% correct). Can only speak for eclipse (well and even there, there are surely many settings I've missed!) and I don't see it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Oh yes, I have successfully done this on IntelliJ (free Community Edition).

Menu > Analyze > Inspect Code...

In the result, select "Java language level migration aids > Explicity type can be replaced with <>"

Right click, run "Apply Fix 'Replace with <>'" And you got diamonds.

There was a bug about diamond on anomymous classes, so some code may not compile after the fix. You'll have to revert them back then.

```
// anonymous class, <> doesn't work.
new Factory<Pig>(){ ... }  
// however IntelliJ may wrongly "fix" it to
new Factory<>(){ ... }   // does not compile.
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was after! I don't think I've got many / any anonymous classes using generics in that way so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I tested this with 2019.1.1 (Ultimate Edition) successfully and the bug you mentioned didn't happen to my code.

Answer (score 8):

If you just want to analyze diamonds and not all the other inspections, use IntelliJ IDEA 12 and go to:

Analyze > Run Inspection by Name... > type "explicit type can be replaced with <>" into the prompt that opens > select the drop down entry and hit Enter

After the inspection runs, you can choose to apply the fix in the Inspection tab at the bottom of the screen.

This is way faster than running every code inspection by using regular 'Analyze > Inspect Code...'

Answer (score 7):

Using Eclipse, you can use a find/replace using regular expressions.

Search for:

```
new (\w+)<.+>
```

And replace for:

```
new $1<>
```

This will also replace any anonymous inner classes, so compilation errors might occur.

Comment: To avoid the issue with anonymous inner classes, if you can assume that the opening `{` is on the same line, you can get away with negative look-ahead: `new (\w+)<.+>([^{]+)(?!\{)$` and replace by `new 1<>\2`

Comment: Also working in NetBeans using Edit > Replace > **Containing Text** `new (\w+)<.+>` and **Replace With** `new $1<>` and do not forget to select **Match: Regular Expression** in the dropdown list above the Replace With field (Literal by default)

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse detects redundant type arguments and offers a quick fix to remove them and create a diamond, see http://thecoderlounge.blogspot.com/2011/07/java-7-support-in-eclipse-jdt-beta-part_22.html

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using Netbeans build-in feature "Inspect and Transform".

1. Open `Refactor` -> `Inspect and Transform`
2. Use `Single Inspection`: `Can Use Diamond`
3. Click `Inspect`
4. Click `Do Refactoring`

Comment: JDK Migration Support -> Can Use Diamond

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the eclipse "Clean Up" tool. (Source -> Clean Up, tab: Unnecessary Code, "Remove redundant type arguments")