# RegEx for Find and replace all ArrayList<something> with ArrayList<> in eclipse

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, java-7, replace

I have recently started using java 7 and I want to use `<>`  **diamond operator** in my existing code. Can anyone tell how to find and replace all the instances of ArrayList to ArrayList<>.

For e.g.:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

would become

`List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();`

I can follow same patter for `Set` and `Map`,too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert existing generics to diamond syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796545/convert-existing-generics-to-diamond-syntax)

Comment: @Thilo : There is a sollution with InteliiJ. But I need a regEx which works in eclipse.

Comment: Doesn't Find `ArrayList<*>` and Replace `ArrayList<>` would work for you?

Comment: @SiB : Nope. :( I tried but not successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking for `([^\t (](List|Map|Set))<[^>]+>` (Case sensitive + Regular expression) and replacing by `$1<>` (Regular expression) worked for me.

**Regex:**

`([^\t (](List|Map|Set))`: any char but a space, a tab or an opening parenthese, followed by List, Map or Set (to match any kind of collections)

- `ArrayList` will match (i.e. `yList`)
- `LinkedList` too (i.e. `dList`)
- but `List` won't (there's no char before List)

`<[^>]+>`: starts with `<`, then any char but `>` 1 time or more, then `>`

`$1<>`: chars that were between the surrounding parentheses followed by `<>`

**How to:**

1) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>

2) [image: Search for]

3) [image: Replace by]

Comment: you mean ([^\t ](ArrayList|HashMap|Set))<[^>]+> ?

Comment: I am weak in regEx. Can you please explain how above regEx works?

Comment: @PriyankDoshi No, because with your regex, how to work with `LinkedList`, `TreeMap` or `SortedSet`?

Comment: @PriyankDoshi Yeah... have another look ;)

Comment: see my answer. I modified yours a lil bit. But thanks for above regEx. :)

Answer (score 1):

After some modification in Above regEx , following works perfact:

```
([^( |^\t](List|Map|Set))<[^>]+>
```

Problem with sp00m's sollution is that it will search

```
 access-modifier   return-type someFunction(List<something> list)
```

also.

for e.g. :

```
void fun(List<Integer> ints)
```

So I added `^(` in initial match.

Comment: You're right about the opening parenthese, but you didn't implement it with the right regex. See my edited answer.