# Save action in Eclipse IDE to convert the java code to the diamond notation

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, diamond-operator

If you have a java version >= 1.7 you can use the diamond notation.

Instead of:

```
List<String> rows = new ArrayList<String>();
```

You can write:

```
List<String> rows = new ArrayList<>();
```

With Eclipse Mars-M4, I have errors when I use the first construct. (Maybe this was already the case with Eclipse Luna version. I did not check):

[image: Java Code]

This is due to this configuration:

Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings in the tree. In the list: Generic Types > Redundant type arguments (1.7 or higher).

[image: Errors/Warnings preference page]

This is set to ERROR. I can of course configure it to IGNORE to remove the error.

I am searching for another solution. Eclipse has the notion of “Additional actions”. I am looking for an action that would rewrite the code to the diamond notation.

Does this action already exist? How can I configure it?

Related question:

- [Convert existing generics to diamond syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796545/convert-existing-generics-to-diamond-syntax) (but this is in NetBeans).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **Eclipse Neon**, just select "Remove redundant type arguments (1.7 or higher)" under the "Unnecessary Code" tab in the "Additional Save Actions" windows (or in the "Edit Clean-up Profile" windows).

[image: Additional Save Actions windows]

Read more in this blog post: [Eclipse Neon: diamond notation as clean-up action](http://jmini.github.io/blog/2016/2016-06-19_eclipse_diamond_notation.html)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible out of the box. You would need to write your own plugin and implement the [`ICleanUp`](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fui%2Fcleanup%2FICleanUp.html) interface.

If you wish to create your own plugin, details on how to create a cleanup and save action can be found here:
[Contributing a clean up and a save action using the clean up extension point](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_api_contributing_a_cleanup.htm)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's a ticket for this targeting eclipse 4.6
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=434788

Comment: Thank you for this input, I saw it live in the Eclipse Neon JDT Webinar today and I have published a [new answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37865780) with a screenshot.